# RDS Replacement in Classic ASP and How to Do the same in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

We have an application that makes heavy use of the `RDS.Dataspace.`

As in :

```
set objDS = CreateObject("RDS.DataSpace")
set objJB = objDS.CreateObject("JBdbio.dbio","http://<%=Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")%>")
```

To instantiate and then:

```
NewQry 2,"QryUpdtItem"  ' To set the name of the stored procedure
AddParam 255,"ISBN",200,txtISBN.value 'params
AddParam 255,"Titl",200,Title.value
m = objJB.UpdateQry(arrPrm) 'do the call to execute the stored procedure
```

Some do updates, some selects, etc

With RDS now obsolete for a number of years.  How can I keep my asp code and have a `Dataspace` to attach to my business object (JBDBIO).

Essentially we just pass all of our params and stored procedure to this business object and then just dish up the results.

And if I were to move this to .net - how could I do the same without ajaxing it -- this is all vbscript code that runs, in effect an application within IE

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly by the last sentence. Do you want to convert it to .Net or do you want to keep the VBScript app?

Comment: I want it to remain as a VBScript app. I was just wondering if it were in .NET what is the equivalent of RDS/Business Object, allowing me to consume data without doing ajax.  We had a guy "rewrite" a couple screen in .net and now it flickers due to the postbacks when it loads data.

Comment: @Mark: Sounds like this guy wasn't using AJAX but plain old ASP.NET forms.

Comment: "Obsolete for a number of years"? That's an understatement! For those too young to remember what RDS is about, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676188(VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Its time for a complete redesign.  VBScript in IE is just not something that you want to be taking forward.

If you still want to use the browser as a means of delivering an inhouse UI then consider ASP.NET-MVC.  If you want to attempt to make the UI smooth in the browser then inclusion of AJAX is the direction you need to take.

OTH in your case it may be worth you considering the delivery of the UI in a non-browser medium.  For example a Silverlight3 using Ria services may be a way forward, XBAP or Click-once installs may also be an option.

No matter what choice you make its going to be a steep learning curve to move away from ancient RDS/VBScript in the client.  You may as well take the opportunity to re-visit the UI behaviour as well.

Comment: A number of months ago I started looking at the click once technology but ran into an impasse a bit as we deploy our application on every one of our customer's servers essentially it is a POS/IC application that runs in IIS.  I think I was having trouble having it go back to their server for checking version as opposed to our server. Its been a while but I can't remember offhand for sure. I'll have to look at ASP.NET-MVC.  I was hoping to just keep the code and find some way around this RDS issue.  My biggest concern is that Microsoft patches RDS in such a way that our systems become crippled

Answer (score 0):

You said it "flickers" on postbacks in the page your guy had rewritten to ASP.NET, didn't the old version "flicker" on postback (submit)? And wow did the .NET code look like if you have not already found any .NET replacement for the database code?

Or have I not understood right, is the VBScript you are talking about client side VBScript? In that case you can actually use the old client side VBScript in the .NET page as well (just as you can run JavaScript on the client side).

If this does not point in any direction to a sollution, I think you might have to provide some more details with code examples, and what you want to acheive.

Comment: The .net code is using ADO.NET and doing post backs to get data. And we never had a submit -- only on page changes. The application POS/IC that runs in a browser.  So you go into POS and if you scan an ISBN to sell it uses the RDS to get the data.  It is all monolithic code in vbscript with a few cabs for User control grids and to control the receipt printer.  But it only flickers when you move from app to app say From Inventory lookup to Cash Register to Reports.  But when you are in each screen all the vbscript is loaded client side and so there is no flicker.  Do I make sense or no?